# How to get most viewed music video on Youtube?

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I need get a list of most viewed music video on **Youtube**.

I used this API:

```
https://youtube.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=snippet%2CcontentDetails%2Cstatistics&chart=mostPopular&regionCode=US&videoCategoryId=10&key=[YOUR_API_KEY]
```

By default `regionCode` is US, I want get results by global.

Can someone help me?

Comment: I think `regionCode=US` is considered _global_ in these cases - it's the default behavior.

Comment: No, regionCode=US is just in US

Comment: ["Can Someone Help Me" is not an actual question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)

Answer (score 0):

You can't really using using the chart means you must include a reagion and the default is the USA.

> string
> The regionCode parameter instructs the API to select a video chart available in the specified region. This parameter can only be used in conjunction with the chart parameter. The parameter value is an ISO 3166-1 alpha-2 country code.

remove `&regionCode=US` Should be the same as US

```
GET https://youtube.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=snippet%2CcontentDetails%2Cstatistics&chart=mostPopular&key=[YOUR_API_KEY]
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply!

Comment: Can I get results in global not US?

Comment: Probably not default appears to be US, and you have to send something.

Comment: This seems to only get the most popular videos as determined by youtube for a particular day, not the most viewed overall for a region

Answer (score 0):

You would have to query [EACH region](https://www.iso.org/obp/ui/#search) and take the videos with the highest cumulative viewCount over all regions. This would be difficult as different regions will have different music videos that are most popular. Unfortunately the API doesn't have a global regionCode option.

Comment: Wouldn't be, @johnh10, more efficient (and effective for that matter) to consider a small subset of all region codes as currently defined that pertain to regions of the globe that are *relevant to this matter* (e.g. in terms of population, economic development, etc)?

Comment: Also,  @johnh10, the aggregate function over all regions (or over the smaller subset of regions that are considered relevant to this matter) would not be *max* but *sum*, isn't it?

Comment: Addendum: *sum* grouped by video ID, of course.